# Magento 2, how to add more option in configuration attribute of product?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2, product-attribute

Using `Magento 2.2`, `Configuration Product - Attribute`. I need to add more select option for **Configuration Product** example **Multiple Select**.

[image]

Comment: You cannot change the existing attribute's "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner". If you try to create new then you will get all options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in your custom module.

**Vendor/Magento/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Observer\HideUnsupportedAttributeTypes">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supportedTypes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="multiselect" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

clear the magento cache. it will show multiple select option in admin.

**Note: Magento2 unsupported some input types for configurable products.**

[image]

Comment: Enable success, but cannot use that new **attribute** for create new product.

Comment: for **Configuration Product**